# FB.Event.subscribe never gets called

Tags: javascript, facebook

This is my Facebook connect Code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".fb-login-button").live('click', function() {
      console.log('click');
      fbEnsureInit(function() {
        console.log('EnsureInit');
        FB.login(function(response) {
          console.log('FB.login');
          // redirect will be done
        }, {scope: 'email'});
      });
  });
});

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '105224616211361', // App ID
    /*channelUrl : '///channel.html', // Channel File // We don't do not to get caching problems with the laguage!*/
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
  // Additional initialization code here
  fbApiInitialized = true;

  // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    try {
      if (response.status == 'connected') {
      console.log('connected');
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/?eID=login&modus=facebook&fb-login=1",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
          console.log("LOGIN");
          window.location.reload();
        }
      })             
    } else {
      console.log('not connected');
      window.location.reload();
    }
  } catch(err) {
    window.location.reload();
   }
});
};

/**
 * Make sure that the FB is initialized!
 */
function fbEnsureInit(callback) {
  if (!window.fbApiInitialized) {
    setTimeout(function() { fbEnsureInit(callback); }, 50);
  } else {
    if (callback) { callback(); }
  }
}

/**
 * Load the JS SDK directly from Facebook
 */
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
      e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js';
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

</script>
```

The SDK gets loaded. I can see the FB- Button and when i click it the Code works until

```
console.log('FB.login');
```

The FB-Popup pops up and nothing happens... This should be the point where:

```
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
```

should get called... but it doesn't.. can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that this only happens, when I am already logged in into Facebook. If I am not logged in, the Login Popup pops up twice(!) and I can login to Facebook and the function FB.Event.Subscribe gets called.

So how can I see if the user is logged in to Facebook and is connected to my application?

And why is the Popup called twice?

Comment: Remove the direct load function of JS SDK at the bottom of the script.

Comment: If I do this, the Image for the FB-Button doesn't load. And i just have the a unclickable text: "Connect with Facebook".

Comment: My mistake. Thought you were loading the SDK twice.

Comment: i changed the Question... I found out that this only happens if i am already logged in into facebook..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `FB.getLoginStatus` if you want to check whether the user is connected to your application.

The login popup is fired twice because the FB-button has a login function too. Remove your ajax call to `$(".fb-login-button").live` and modify your login button like this:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

Comment: how do you mean: "Remove your ajax call to $(".fb-login-button").live" ? And besides this, my facebook button is exactly like this except for: "Login with Facebook" between the div's.

Comment: In that function you are calling `FB.login` which is initiated by the login button too. That is the reason you get two popups.

Comment: i see your point but i dont know how to do it. How can i remove FB.Login but keep my functions there?

Comment: Don't use the Facebook login button. Make one yourself.